# where to store confidential data like decryption key in android so that it can never be found by hacker

Tags: java, android, security, encryption

I am creating a app where i need a decryption key to decrypt videos and other data . i need to play videos offline so i need to store the key in the app . So if i use shared pref to store my key or directly in the string it can be easily hacked . and my data will not be secured any more . So where should i keep my key so that no one can find my key on decompiling the app or rooting phone to get to the key.
I am thinking about where should i store data

- sqlite
- shared prefrence
- text file
- string file
- static variable

Comment: which algo used for encrypt/decrypt data? I suggest u have to never store plain private key.

Comment: there is no absolutly safe way to store the data.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html See section "security".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to secure your encryption key in NDK.

### Step 1

```
private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception 
{
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
    return encrypted;
}

private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception     
{
    SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
    byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
    return decrypted;
}
```

### Step 2

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();  
bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos); 
byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();  

byte[] keyStart = "encryption key".getBytes();
KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
sr.setSeed(keyStart);
kgen.init(128, sr); 
SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
byte[] key = skey.getEncoded();    

// encrypt
byte[] encryptedData = encrypt(key,b);
// decrypt
byte[] decryptedData = decrypt(key,encryptedData);
```

### Step 3

```
static {
        System.loadLibrary("library-name");
    }

public native String getSecretKey();
```

### Step 4

And save in a file using NDK the following function:

```
Java_com_example_exampleApp_ExampleClass_getSecretKey(
           JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz )
{
    return (*env)->NewStringUTF(env, "mySecretKey".");
}
```

### Step 4

Now we can easily retrieve our key and use it to encrypt our data.

```
byte[] keyStart = getSecretKey().getBytes();
```

Reference : [How to store the Credentials securely in Android](http://codetalk.de/?p=86)

Comment: He's not trying to store credentials. He's trying to hide information from the user.

Comment: @Kayaman FYI `I am creating a app where i need a decryption key to decrypt videos and other data . i need to play videos offline so i need to store the key in the app` is written in question

Comment: I know what he wrote. He's trying to hide the encryption key from the user so the user can't take the videos out and distribute them in other forms. Otherwise it doesn't make sense to store encrypted video.

Comment: Wouldn't the application of some sort of well-known DRM System be better suited then?

Answer (score 3):

If the decryption key is at any point accessible to the application, it's accessible to any potential evildoer. This is a fact.

If your requirements are:

- Videos encrypted, i.e. only playable through your app
- Playable offline
- Secured so you can't decrypt or view the videos through other means

Then what you have are impossible requirements.

Comment: I just thought about if it would be at least somewhat safe if he encrypted the decryption key with a user-defined PIN or Mantra. Then he could decrypt the decryption key with that PIN or Mantra, which is stored in User's head, not on the phone ... ? Maybe?

Comment: I'm pretty sure he wants to secure it from the user, so that won't bring any additional security.

Comment: Your comment on Chintan's answer brought the idea to my head if some sort of DRM system wouldn't be better suited for this type of usecase?

Comment: I'm not sure Android supports [TPM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_Platform_Module). [Apparently not.](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/102815/is-there-are-any-mechanism-available-in-android-platform-for-remote-attestation)

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.3.html At least from 4.3 they support app-private keystores. (See section "security" in linked document) Hardwaresupport can be checked: "While not all Android-powered devices support storage on hardware, you can check at runtime if hardware-backed storage is available by calling KeyChain.IsBoundKeyAlgorithm()."

Comment: @fildor thanks for your answer . that can help me securing the key atleast for version above 4.3 . and Even NDK can be used but that can be bit complicated

Answer (score 0):

Create your own directory under the main Android default directory 
In your directory create multiple directories and hide the file in one of it.
Other than the that there is no really secure way

Comment: Security by obscurity is no security! Or did I understand incorrectly?

Comment: You can't encrypt you can only hide

Comment: Now I am completely confused. Why can't I encrypt? Do you mean the path?

Comment: The path I mean and if you want to encrypt the key that is if possible you have to look up on encryption and decryption algorithms